# Is it possible to create that borderlands edge outline look on a transparent object? In BGE?

Tags: transparency

Can I add an edge outline to an object in bge (say a human) thats transparent? Ive tried everything except code and cant figure out a way to do it. Thanx for the answers!

Comment: do you mean like a wireframe, or only the camera-visible contour, in game?

Comment: I mean like a stylistic effect. kinda like the one used in cel shading with the edge outlines that mimic inking in a comic book just without the toon shading since the object is transparent. What Im trying to do is create a game with a sketchy notebook look. What i was planning on doing is having a background image with a texture of a binder paper. All the models would only have their edges rendered with a noisy black outline so it would look like drawings in a notebook.

Comment: Try this thread. It's called cell shading. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?264326-Blender-Game-Cartoon-Shader

Comment: as I get it what you want is something like a freestyle edges effect but in real time game engine... this I think is not possible with blender now. It could also depend on your game, but I guess if you don't wish to use pre-rendered objects...